hi guys, do you recognize this? is ラ... or う... i don't know i'm confused
personally, i think it's ラ... because the line(-) above and the フ are parallel. or i don't know


That looks like ラ.  Context might help to be sure.  But otherwise, I would go with that.

Written text, especially those in manga, tend to be a bit sloppy. It usually is easy enough to tell from the context. The only time ラ would be used like this is if the speaker is repeating a work with ラ. If they're be chastised or proven wrong, う (and うっ, くっ, and ぐっ) is very common.

We don't do translations, proofreading, character identification, or audio deciphering.

When interpreted in isolation, it's impossible to judge precisely. The context and your knowledge about words are far more important than the appearance of the character. Imagine how you distinguish between a handwritten "I" (uppercase i) and "l" (lowercase L) in English.
In this case, the character's appearance itself may be indeed somewhat closer to ラ than to う, but I would say it is more likely to be う. This is because "う…" makes perfect sense as an interjection meaning "oh..." or "uh-oh", but "ラ…" is not something we commonly say. However, if the context involves musical notes (do-re-mi) or words beginning with ラ, for example, then it could be ラ. You need to see the context.
